# Short or relative URLs in python traceback?

Tags: python, traceback

How to setup python interpreter/compiler do not return full URLs in traceback return for a more convenient perception?

For example, when I run tests:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later (__main__.NewVisitorTest)
test: can start list here and get it later
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functional_tests.py", line 25, in test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later
    header_text = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('h1').text
  File "/Users/slava/PycharmProjects/SuperListProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 530, in find_element_by_tag_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value=name)
  File "/Users/slava/PycharmProjects/SuperListProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/Users/slava/PycharmProjects/SuperListProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/slava/PycharmProjects/SuperListProj/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: h1
```

change to:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later (__main__.NewVisitorTest)
test: can start list here and get it later
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functional_tests.py", line 25, in test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later
    header_text = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('h1').text
  File "/.../remote/webdriver.py", line 530, in find_element_by_tag_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value=name)
  File "/.../remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/.../remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/.../remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: h1
```

If it possible at all.

Comment: This is interesting question... But I don't think it's a good thing because packages might come from all around the place, depending on your PATH. Cutting the path would cut useful info to trace the problem

Comment: As you see, files in your current folder are shown with a short relative path. Files from your virtual env are shown with a full path. This is to prevent different library paths (interpreter installation, venv, local…) to be confused.

Comment: In 90% I need to skip information about file full path and focus on errors stack. But path's to files create to many visual noise.